# Build a Dockerfile for angular

Tags: angular, docker

I'm following countless articles on the web for building a docker container for testing angular.  In all examples, I end up with this error:

```
 => ERROR [6/6] RUN  npm run build --omit=dev                                                                                                                                        
0.7s
------
 > [6/6] RUN  npm run build --omit=dev:
#10 0.687
#10 0.687 > edi-tracker@0.0.0 build
#10 0.687 > ng build
#10 0.687
#10 0.695 sh: 1: ng: Permission denied
```

After testing a lot, I can see that the problem is, ng is never installed or added to PATH.  npm commands work fine, but when npm hands off to angular-cli, it fails.  But it's puzzling that nobody seems to encounter this error.  My Dockerfile is below.  Can anyone give suggestions to resolve this ng: Permission denied error?

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:latest AS build  
USER node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --chown=node:node package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY --chown=node:node . .
RUN  npm run build --omit=dev
### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: in the latter you have "RUN  npm run build --omit=dev" is this the line that WAS "ng build"?

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file to ignore `node_modules`? Otherwise it looks like they are overwritten by the second copy.

Comment: @Cody no. From what I can infer from the logs, `ng build` is called as subprocess of `npm build`.

Comment: instead you can just build the project in your local machine and the create a docker container to just host the built website using nginx or any http server

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:latest AS build
#USER node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY  . .
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@14.2.1
RUN npm run build --omit=dev
### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: is this `@angular/cli@14.2.1` dependency in your package.json? Because if its not there you should add it and remove the need to install the cli globally

Comment: to be clear, my package.json file does contain "@angular/cli": "^14.2.1", in devDependencies, yet RUN npm install doesn't seem to load angular-cli properly.  Removing the line RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@14.2.1 from Dockerfile results in ng: Permission denied error.